# I am trying to execute jdbc transaction.But the database is not updated once I run the code

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, transactions

I have used the following code in Eclipse.The database is not updated once I run the code.It still shows the same value.I even ran the sql query in the database which is running fine but once I run my java code nothing is being updated..

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.Properties;
    public class ExpTran {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream io = new FileInputStream("config/db.properties");
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.load(io);
        Class.forName(p.getProperty("driver"));
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(p.getProperty("url"),p);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        int i = stmt.executeUpdate("update tutorials.account set amount=amount-500 where acc_no='A002'");
        i += stmt.executeUpdate("update tutorials.account set amount=amount+500 where acc_no='A003'");
        if(i!=2)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception");
            throw new SQLException();
        }
        System.out.println(i);  
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if(con!=null){
            try {
                con.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(con!=null){
            try {
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: where are you committing the transaction?

Answer (score 2):

You have to explicitly commit your changes calling `con.commit();` if you define `con.setAutoCommit(false);`

Also avoid using a single try/catch/finally block for multiple operations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();

    try (FileInputStream propertiesInputStream = new FileInputStream("config/db.properties")) {
        properties.load(propertiesInputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading properties file.", e);
    }

    String driverClassName = properties.getProperty("driver");
    try {
        Class.forName(driverClassName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error loading JDBC driver class.", e);
    }

    String databaseUrl = properties.getProperty("url");

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseUrl, properties)) {
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);

        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        executeUpdateAndCheck(stmt, "update tutorials.account set amount=amount-500 where acc_no='A002'");
        executeUpdateAndCheck(stmt, "update tutorials.account set amount=amount+500 where acc_no='A003'");

        connection.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static void executeUpdateAndCheck(Statement stmt, String command) throws SQLException {
    int result = stmt.executeUpdate(command);

    if (result == 0) {
        stmt.getConnection().rollback();
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either do

```
conn.commit();
```

A call to commit() will write all the changes to the database, and is needed because auto-commit is turned off. If an exception occurs, then you'll need to catch it and issue the command

```
conn.rollback();
```

to restore the database back to its original state.

Otherwise, do

```
conn.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Then each individual statement will be automatically commuted to the database. The trouble there is that each statement will be executed in its own transaction. If an exception occurs after executing the first statement, the 2nd statement will not be executed which might leave the DB in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace this:

```
   con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

With this here:

```
  System.out.println(i);
  con.commit();
```

Or set it to `true`:

```
  con.setAutoCommit(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

insert or update is not getting reflectd in the database as you are setting : `con.setAutoCommit(false);`

Replace this line with :

`con.commit();`

OR

`con.setAutoCommit(true);`

Comment: A `con.commit()` should be placed **after** the update statements, **or** don't set auto commit (the default is true).

Answer (score 0):

You defined `con.setAutoCommit(false);`, so you need to commit the connection when finished operations.

For this use [`Connection.commit()`](http://DriverManager.getConnection():

```
if(i!=2) {
   System.out.println("Exception");
   throw new SQLException();
} else {
   con.commit();
}
```